# Rotating a Linked List C

Tags: c, linked-list

I am currently solving sum problems of list and function  and i came across this question i.e rotate a linked list by k anti clockwise. 
Here is the code for same

```
void rotate_k(struct list *node,int k)
{
   int count=0;
   struct list *knode,*ptr=node;
   while(ptr!=NULL && count < k)
    {
      ptr=ptr->next;
      count++; 
     }
    knode=ptr;
    while(ptr->next!=NULL)
     {
      ptr=ptr->next;
      }
    ptr->next =node;
    node=knode->next;
    knode->next=NULL;
  }
```

Lets say if input is 1->2->3->4->5->6 and k=4.

The output should be 5->6->1->2->3->4 but the code gives the output 1->2->3->4->5 .
Help needed :)

Comment: what did the debugger say?

Comment: think what needs to be done to the list. Find teh kth element; make it the new head and make the old tail point to the old head. I dont see code to do the last 2 parts. Also return the new head

Comment: The second while loop goes to the end of list and the ptr->next=node make the tail points to the old head. 
node=knode->next  makes 5 new head of the list

Answer (score 3):

You are not modifying the original list (`node` parameter)

```
struct list *rotate_k(struct list *node,int k)
{
   int count=0;
   struct list *knode,*ptr=node;
   while(ptr!=NULL && count < k)
   {
      ptr=ptr->next;
      count++; 
   }
   knode=ptr;
   while(ptr->next!=NULL)
   {
      ptr=ptr->next;
   }
   ptr->next =node;
   node=knode->next;     
   knode->next=NULL;

   return knode; //<-- THIS IS THE NEW LIST
}
```

Also, `knode->next=NULL` is strange; you should do at the node that is (was) previous to `knode` (this is what is deleting the 6 from your results).

Comment: from what I read from your code (and the results), `knode` points at `5` which is the element that you desire. Anyway test it.

Answer (score 3):

SJuan's method is correct but if you want to do it your way without using a return value, then you need to use a double pointer for node. Remember, C makes copies of variables you pass into a function. If the original root node was a pointer (which I'm assuming it was) than you need to make a pointer to a pointer otherwise you are just making changes to a copy of the root node pointer, not the actual root node pointer.

```
void rotate_k(struct list **node, int k)
{
   int count = 0;
   struct list *knode, *ptr = *node;
   while(ptr != NULL && count < k)
   {
      ptr = ptr->next;
      count++; 
   }
   knode = ptr;
   while(ptr->next != NULL)
   {
      ptr = ptr->next;
   }
   ptr->next = *node;
   *node = knode->next;     
   knode->next = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void rotate_list_right(listnode** head, int k)
    {
    if( !head || !*head )
        {
        printf( "\nrotate_list_right: empty list = so return \n" );
        return;
        }
    if( k < 1 )
        {
        printf( "\nrotate_list_right:invalid input: k must be >= 1 \n" );
        return;
        }

    listnode* post = *head;
    listnode* curr = *head;

    /* move post by k nodes */
    while(k--)
        {
        post = post->next;
        if( !post ) /* k is bigger than length of the list */
            {
            printf( "\nrotate_list_right:invalid input: k must be smaller than list size \n" );
            return;
            }
        }

    /* move curr to kth-last node */
    while(post->next)
        {
        curr = curr->next;
        post = post->next;
        }

    /* currs' next is new header */
    listnode* tmp = *head;
    *head = curr->next;
    curr->next = 0;

    //join post
    post->next = tmp;
    }
```